# iOS App switch CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, xcode

For our iOS app we have mis-used the CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion (we swapped them, don't ask why...)
But now we want to change them and use them in a right way, but we are not sure how to do this.

Currently it is configured like this:

```
CFBundleShortVersionString: 505101
CFBundleVersion: 3.4.0
```

With the new release (4.0.0) we want to set things right and in an idealistic world change it to:

```
CFBundleShortVersionString: 4.0.0
CFBundleVersion: 20150623
```

But iTunes Connect doesn't agree; because the previous CFBundleShortVersionString is higher than the new one.

What is the proper way to set things right in this case?

Comment: I think it's too late once your app is released.  It will confuse the whole system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible within the current iTunes Connect, because user devices are notified of app updates due to a check on the short version numbers.

Your only options are to either suck it up and boast about it, or to create a new app bundle where the settings are correct.